# expandable iOS tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom tableViewControlelr that has rounded card view cells. The tableViewCells also have the ability to be clicked and when clicked, it expands.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.selectedIndex = indexPath
        self.didExpandCell()

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if isExpanded && self.selectedIndex == indexPath{
            return 300
        }
        return 126
```

within my tableviewcell, I have a custom view that is white, this is what allows for the card view appearance and it is also rounded. When the cell is not clicked, the cell is the standard height and looks like this: 
[image]

And when the cell is clicked, it expands and looks like this:[image]

As you can see when the cell is not clicked, the bottom part is straight and not rounded, I attempted to use this code to make it rounded but it did not work.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell

if TableView.rowHeight == 126 {

            cell.CustomView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 7, y: 8, width: 359, height: 20))

            return cell
        }
        else{

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem doing this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell
if isExpanded && self.selectedIndex == indexPath {
            cell.CustomView.frame = CGRect(x: 7, y: 8, width: 359, height: 283)
        }
       else {
       cell.CustomView.frame = CGRect(x: 7, y: 8, width: 359, height: 116)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem can be resolve by just taking test label inside the view that make view round not cell when the cell expand remove radius from view.
    or you can set the particular corner radius eg top-left,top-right,.bottomLeft , .bottomRight.

```
Use below example to set the corner radius

  let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
    rectShape.bounds = self.myView.frame
    rectShape.position = self.myView.center
    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.myView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft , .bottomRight , .topLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).cgPath

     self.myView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
     self.myView.layer.mask = rectShape
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custom view is always the fully expanded height as you never do anything to make it otherwise (at least going by the code you have shared).

The reason your attempted fix doesn't work is because TableView.rowHeight is the height used for cells if you are not using the delegate method to determine what the cell height is and you are using the delegate method.  TableView.rowHeight will always be what you set it to initially and will not vary by cell so it will never match (or always match if you set it to 126).

If you want to get the effect you are after I would suggest looking into either auto layout or the auto resizing mask to make the custom view size dynamically as the cell does.